# Is there a way to get the value of the next element in for loop SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the SQL that I have written

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    CURSOR overview IS
        SELECT e.last_name, e.first_name, d.department_name, e.department_id
        FROM employees e, departments d
        where e.department_id = d.department_id
        ORDER BY e.department_id;
    lastdepartment employees.department_id%TYPE := 0;
BEGIN
    FOR i in overview LOOP
        IF lastdepartment != i.department_id THEN
            lastdepartment := i.department_id;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-' || i.department_id||' '||i.department_name);        
        END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---'||i.last_name ||' '||i.first_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

It outputs the information so that it shows the first and last name of all employees in a certain department with the help of a for loop. The main idea is that there a lot of employees in the same department and I do not need to output the department for each one, but rather make something as an overview. Example output shown below:

```
-10 Administration
---Whalen Jennifer
-20 Marketing
---Fay Pat
---Hartstein Michael
-30 Purchasing
---Tobias Sigal
---Colmenares Karen
---Baida Shelli
```

The method I am using is storing the department number of the **PREVIOUS** element and checking whether it matches with the current element. I would like to know if there is a way to check the department_id of the current element and the department_id of the **NEXT** element as this would remove the variable I have created.

Comment: Probably you can read about the Lead() analytical function

Comment: On a side note: You are using an ancient comma-separated join syntax that was made redundant in Standard SQL 1992. Use explicit ANSI joins instead (`FROM a INNER JOIN b ON …`).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thank you for the side note, I will keep this in mind in the future. Initially I was using JOIN but I had a lot of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to number the employees per department. When reading a department's first employee you display the department.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  CURSOR overview IS
    SELECT
      e.last_name, e.first_name, d.department_name, e.department_id,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.department_id ORDER BY e.employee_id) AS rn
    FROM employees e
    JOIN departments d ON d.department_id = e.department_id
    ORDER BY e.department_id, e.employee_id;
BEGIN
  FOR i in overview LOOP
    IF i.rn = 1 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-' || i.department_id || ' ' || i.department_name);    
    END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---' || i.last_name || ' ' || i.first_name);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use nested loops: outer for departments, inner for employees:

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_d in (select deptno, dname from dept order by deptno) loop
  3      dbms_output.put_line(cur_d.deptno ||' '|| cur_d.dname);
  4      for cur_e in (select ename from emp where deptno = cur_d.deptno) loop
  5        dbms_output.put_line('-- ' || cur_e.ename);
  6      end loop;
  7    end loop;
  8  end;
  9  /
10 ACCOUNTING
-- CLARK
-- KING
-- MILLER
20 RESEARCH
-- SMITH
-- JONES
-- SCOTT
-- ADAMS
-- FORD
30 SALES
-- ALLEN
-- WARD
-- MARTIN
-- BLAKE
-- TURNER
-- JAMES
40 OPERATIONS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```